# Running around for Exploration experience

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What is **exploration experience**? This is boosted by the *Exploration* trait on items, do we normally get enough base xp to make this a worthwhile trait to use? Is it possible to strategically increase the rate of getting exploration xp, besides just running around exploring the map (which would be done eventually for solving quests anyway).

Comment: Note: The Exploration trait has been removed from the game with the DB dlc, and items which had it now have the **Prosperous** trait instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new area or location is discovered (i.e when a name pops up), you are awarded XP.

From personal experience, discovering a place is like killing 2 or 3 mobs of the area. This not much, but still a nice bonus.

So if you want to level up faster, a full armor with *Exploration* trait would have a small impact - a *really* small impact.

#### TL;DR: Solve quests.

Comment: I guess Exploration armor sets are only useful for an alt running around to get Skyshards asap :p. Which rules it out for a new player like me, who wants to explore at my own pace.

Comment: @Alok Good choice. The game has flaws, but exploration is great and the lore is really developped !